# Named Function Expression : Difference between var bar = function () {} & var bar = function foo(){}

Tags: javascript, function

Can any one help in understanding the difference between following two function expressions:

```
a) var bar = function() {};
b) var bar = function foo() {};
```

I have been writing the way it has been written in a).
What is the importance of giving function name as "foo" in b)?

How is a) different from b)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method a: a variable named `bar` that refers to the anonymous function. function can only be used by using the variable `bar` wherever it is in scope.

Method b: a variable name `bar` that refers to a named function `foo`. `foo` can still be used by name anywhere it is in scope along with using `bar` as well.

As Paulpro mentioned - `foo` is only in scope inside the function itself, nice for recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Naming a function may not affect the code, but it's useful for debugging and in constructor functions, it defines the name of the prototype.